# Express 4, Body Parser and Router

Tags: express, router

I am using Express 4 with a Body Parser so that I can parse though different JSON payloads that are sent with each request. I attempted to separate concerns with my different routers but using the new route object in express 4. However, the req.body object in a post still parses to nothing even though I am sending application/json payload. 
Here is a snippet of code to show what I am trying to achieve

```
//Setup
var compression    = require('compression'); //gzip
var express        = require('express');
var app            = express();
var bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
app.use(compression());

// configure app to use bodyParser()
// this will let us get response data from a POST
var json_body_parser = bodyParser.json();
var urlencoded_body_parser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true });
app.use(json_body_parser);
app.use(urlencoded_body_parser);

var port = process.env.PORT || 8081;

var router = express.Router();
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // log each request to the console
    console.log(req.method, req.url);
    next();
});

router.route('/test')
    .get(function(req, res) { //Get All
        //do some stuff get stuff
    })
    .post(function(req, res) { //Create
        console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body)); //Empty ???
        res.json({ "message": "yeah!" });
        //Do some post stuff
    });

app.use('/api', router);

app.listen(port);

console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

Example Post using PostMan

```
POST /api/test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8081
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{ "data":"4edd40c86762e0fb12000013" }
```

How do I get the request body in the POST request?

Comment: I forgot to add the Content-Type in the post request. This is not a problem with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a problem with the content type on the post request. It should have been set to Content-Type - application/json. I confirmed this was the cause.